# Are coffee tree berries edible?

Tags: coffee-berries

According this [legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee#Legendary_accounts), somebody called Sheik Omar chewed on coffee berries when living in exile. It is mentioned he found them too bitter at the time. But is it *possible* to eat them?

Also, according [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffea#Ecology): *"The caffeine in coffee "beans" is a natural plant defense against herbivory, i.e., a toxic substance that protects the seeds of the plant."*

But clearly that does not poison us humans.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### *TL;DR* Yes, they are edible and non-toxic to humans.

Coffee cherries, as they are properly called, are a thin papery skin and attached mucilage (what we think of as the flesh of the fruit). Coffee cherries are consumed as a drink, cascara, by coffee farmers in Latin America.

Coffee cherries contain more caffeine than coffee, on average, as they do not go though a roasting process. Depending on the green processing / pulping / milling process the coffee went through, coffee cherries often have a bitter and gamy flavor.